# Video is not clear after adding watermark in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, avkit

I am just adding watermark to video. I added to video and loaded into photo library.

After that I tried to play, that video file is fully blurred. But, file is playing well. Water mark is added.

I downloaded project from https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos and run it.

I am trying this in simulator. Kindly guide me.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]